# MiniUPnP and UPnP devices

Tags: upnp

i'm trying to work with MiniUPnP. During testing testupnpigd.py i've got an error:

> Discovering... delay=200ms 0 device(s)
>   detected Exception : No UPnP device
>   discovered

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Verify using another tool that your SSDP broadcasts actually get replies.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your router is not yet supported by MiniUPnP? Try contacting the author about it.